# SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() does not have affect

Tags: c++, c, security, ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL for my server developed in C.

OpenSSL is called in my source code in the following way:

```
SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{
    SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    method = TLSv1_2_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

int main(int count, char *Argc[])
{   
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;

    // Initialize the SSL library
    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* initialize SSL */
    ...
}
```

I tested my server with [ssllabs.com](https://sslabs.com). and I got weaks in the supported ciphers on my server.

[image]

I tried to add the following line after initiating context

```
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA:!NULL-RSA");
```

But nothing change!

How to disable these weak ciphers in my server?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA:!NULL-RSA");
> ```

This cipher setting does nothing to disable typical weak ciphers. In contrary: this enables practically all ciphers  (due to `ALL`) including many weak ciphers and only disables a very few NULL ciphers.

At the very least you should use `HIGH` and not `ALL`. Even better recommendations can be found [at the Mozilla server configuration](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Another alternative configuration link: https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/